# Disable class attribute while on Design Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, caliburn.micro, custom-attributes

I'm writing a WPF Application and implementing custom security authentication and authorization by using a custom principal, and it works great. I'm using CaliburnMicro as the MVVM Framework. And I'm using it's design mode support, so on every View I have:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```

Then, when I'm working within Visual Studio I can view and edit my controls, populated by the View Model. The problem, however, is the `PrincipalPermission` attribute:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
public class MyViewModel : Screen
```

Because if I set it, then that View Model gets restricted (so only authenticated users can view it) and it works great on runtime; where I do check for that and redirect to login View Model; but then I lost all the design capabilities of the WPF Editor (because the design editor shows a blank screen). If I comment that attribute, and clean/rebuild the project, then the editor works again; but that's not a real option since I have almost 70 views and we are a group of 13 developers/designers.

**Is there a way so can I restrict that attribute to be set only if it's not in design mode? So we can design/develop and test without being manually commenting 70+ views?**

Comment: You use this attribute to restrict access based on current Windows user?

Comment: @Evk no. I implemented a custom authentication service against an existing service bus. But I'm using the framework built-in mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way those CAS attributes work (related permission is basically embedded in resulting dll at compile time), you have to create your own `PrincipalPermission`, but it's not hard, because you can proxy all work to real `PrincipalPermission`:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Serializable]
public sealed class PrincipalPermissionProxy : IPermission, IUnrestrictedPermission
{
    private readonly PrincipalPermission _inner;
    public PrincipalPermissionProxy(PrincipalPermission inner) {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IPermission Copy()
    {
        return _inner.Copy();
    }

    public void Demand() {
        // NOTE here we check if we are running under designer and if so - ignore demand
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            return;
        _inner.Demand();
    }

    public void FromXml(SecurityElement e)
    {
        _inner.FromXml(e);
    }

    public IPermission Intersect(IPermission target)
    {
        return _inner.Intersect(target);
    }

    public bool IsSubsetOf(IPermission target)
    {
        return _inner.IsSubsetOf(target);
    }

    public bool IsUnrestricted()
    {
        return _inner.IsUnrestricted();
    }

    public SecurityElement ToXml()
    {
        return _inner.ToXml();
    }

    public IPermission Union(IPermission target)
    {
        return _inner.Union(target);
    }
}
```

Then we copy PrincipalPermissionAttribute to return our permission (attribute is very simple to we just copy it completely):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public bool Authenticated { get; set; } = true;

    public MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction action)
        : base(action) {

    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission() {
        if (this.Unrestricted)
            return new PrincipalPermissionProxy(new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        return new PrincipalPermissionProxy(new PrincipalPermission(this.Name, this.Role, this.Authenticated));
    }
}
```

Then replace all your attributes with `MyPermissionAttribute` (with some fancy name of course :)) and done - designer will now work fine.

Note when you will test this with WPF designer - not just rebuild the project but **kill** all XDesProc.exe processes (those are processes of WPF designer).

Comment: Thanks @Evk, I'll try and let you know.